# Excel macro to get all combinations for an array string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a macro function to generate a string which has all combinations of an array string and then check against another string if it is part of those combinations.

Example:
In `A1`, I have `a;b;c;d;e`, and in `B1` I have `b;d;a;c;e`. I am looking for a function to put in `C1` so that it looks for all combinations of `A1` and verify for `B1`. If the `B1` string exists in one of the `A1` combinations then `C1` should be Passed or else it should be Failed.
Example Possible combinations for `A1`:

```
a;b;c;d;e
b;c;d;e;a
c;d;e;a;b
d;e;a;b;c
e;a;b;c;d
b;a;c;e;d 
etc
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a starting point.

```
Function IsCombination(test As Range, base As Range) As Boolean
    Dim testArr() As String, baseArr() As String, i As Integer

    testArr = Split(test, ";") //B1 in your example
    baseArr = Split(base, ";") //Al in your example

    If UBound(testArr) <> UBound(baseArr) Then
        IsCombination = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(testArr)
            If InStr(Join(baseArr), testArr(i)) = 0 Then
                IsCombination = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    IsCombination = True
End Function
```

First a check is made to see if the both strings are the same length. If not then they cannot be a combination match.

Then each character is checked to see if it is in the other string array. If every character finds a match then it is a combination.